# I can't deploy a Go module to App Engine using the google.golang.org/appengine modules

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

From the latest material I can read, and also based on documentation on certain APIs (for example, [the Go Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/)), I'm supposed to use `google.golang.org/appengine` etc. instead of the old `appengine/...` paths. However, when I try to deploy using gcloud preview app deploy, I get the following error:

> Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
>
> ```
> 2016/01/14 14:32:43 go-app-builder: build timing: 2×6g (113ms total), 0×6l (0 total)
> 2016/01/14 14:32:43 go-app-builder: failed running 6g: exit status 1
>
> server/alexa.go:10: can't find import: "golang.org/x/net/context"
> ```

The `golang.org/x/net/context` package supposedly replaces the old `appengine/context` one, but it doesn't appear to be available in the deployment server's `GOROOT`.

I tried including all the dependencies and their dependencies in my package repo but that only lead me to this obscure error (the directory it's complaining about actually exists):

> Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
>
> ```
> 2016/01/14 14:27:04 go-app-builder: build timing: 18×6g (1.819s total), 0×6l (0 total)
> 2016/01/14 14:27:04 go-app-builder: failed running 6g: exit status 1
>
> github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/testdata/my_test/test.pb.go:27: can't find import: "github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/testdata/multi"
> ```

Have I misunderstood the documentation and am only supposed to use the old packages?

Comment: Does `goapp deply <app>` work?  I've not had any problems serving locally with the new libs but (i) I've been using `goapp serve`, (ii) I've not yet tried deploying it.

Comment: Is this issue still occurring for you, or is it transient?

Comment: @Nick: I can't get it to work with `gcloud`. I did manage to work around it by using the old `appcfg.py` tool, although that requires some additional configuration. For now I've written a deploy script that will deploy a version using `appcfg.py` and then set it as default using `gcloud`.

Comment: In the second example, how did you go about including the dependencies in your package repo? Are you using the go vendor experiment?

Comment: @JeffSisson Nope I was just including them at the root level which works for third-party packages in App Engine Go (I guess Google does some trickery under the hood).

Comment: If you can provide some minimal code necessary to reproduce the behaviour, along with some technical details about your system, paths, versions, etc. you could probably get this addressed in the [Public Issue Tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), as it seems this is not a user-issue but a possible SDK issue.

Comment: I see that [Issue 12670](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12670) has not been updated in some time. Though `goapp deploy` is the recommended command-line tool for Go GAE application deployment (which essentially wraps `appcfg.py update`), have you or are you still experiencing this issue when using [`gcloud preview app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/deploy)?

Comment: the Google's documentation are very confusing now, some of their example use import "appengine" while others use "google.golang.org/appengine", and there's not a clue how you should set things up to use the "google.golang.org/appengine" version and everything that comes along with it does not work, for example, "google.golang.org/appengine/log".

It's a shame Google put so much time on their cloud product but yet having a bad documentation screw things up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a `go get golang.org/x/net/context` to save that package in your go src directory.  Though, when working with App Engine it is not necessary.  Those libraries can be imported and used, but they mostly focused on applications run outside of App Engine, i.e. Container Engine or Compute Engine.  They essentially hook into the RESTful APIs Google cooked up for those services.  If you decide to work directly with Google Cloud Storage you would need those libraries since App Engine expects you to use Blobstore instead.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem in this case because I am only using the supported Go packages (and development server runs correctly). The issue has been reported here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12670

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gosdk, just run `goapp get` in the same directory as your .go file and it will download and install the dependencies to your gosdk installation. You then deploy the app again and it should compile without problem.

When it's working there's no prompt and files will be downloaded to gosdk\gopath\src

After fininshing there will be a warning message which can be ignored:

> go install: no install location for directory
>   C:\your_current_directory outside GOPATH
>           For more details see: go help gopath

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this issue is now fixed with **gcloud version 142**.
One should now be able to deploy using `gcloud beta app deploy --project <project> app.yaml`. Use `gcloud components update` to upgrade the command line.

- Here is an example project to see it work: https://github.com/aubm/my-test-app
- And the Travis build logs: https://travis-ci.org/aubm/my-test-app/builds/198057096